# Creating sql queries for reports in java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I want to create a parametrized query to receive something from the database. This query is big, that big that it is not really possible to put it in a @Query annotation in a CrudRepository and also it should be very flexible so that depending on parameters it may add a join or a with segment to the query.
The way I saw this situation being handled was building the query in a String variable and then passing that string to a JdbcTemplate or being executed in another ways. Something like that:

```
String sql = getWith(params) + getJoin(params) + getWhere(params);
```

These methods can get very big and ugly.
Is there a way I can achieve my goal more elegantly?

Comment: why not putting it in a procedure?

Comment: That doesn't really change the complexity, does it ? I want to avoid the mess of having hundreds of lines of code, and have them more readable.

Comment: if your question is how to simplify that query , you need to paste your query here